# Некорректно удаляется запись из mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Есть новости на странице. У каждой кнопка в виде корзины (удалить).
Пытаюсь удалить через ajax. Удаляется всегда последняя новость, а не та которую выбрал.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function delpost1(){
    Snackbar.show({text: 'Удалено!', actionText: 'Закрыть!', duration: 100000});
    var dlt = $('.delpost').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "system/del_post.php",
      data: dlt,
    });
  }
  $('#btndel').click(function() {
    $.post("system/del_post.php");
  })
</script>
```

**PHP & HTML:**

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" class="delpost">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" id="btndel" onclick="delpost1()" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash-2 delete-note"><polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline><path d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2"></path><line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line><line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line></svg>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" maxlength="12" value="'; echo $row['id']; echo '">
</form>';
```

обработчик:

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
$id=htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);

    include 'bd.php';
    
$res2=mysql_query("DELETE FROM `posts` WHERE `id`='$id'");
}
```

надо чтобы удалялась нужная запись а не последняя. не могу понять в чем трабл.

Comment: а где вы передаете параметры удаления?

Comment: $('#btndel').click(function() {
                    $.post("system/del_post.php");
                    })

Comment: Вы не передаёте id удаляемого объекта в вашем post

Comment: вот в этой строке айди новости:
<input type="hidden" name="id" class="formj" maxlength="12" value="'; echo $row['id']; echo '">

Comment: заключено в форму все, вместе с кнопкой. по клику на кнопку запускается функция delpost1 .

Comment: да в строке есть а где в пост он?

Comment: var dlt = $('.delpost').serialize(); вот сюда же передается. из формы

Comment: Если вы правильно передаёте на сервер то приложите код del_post.php который обрабатывает ваш пост

Comment: <?php
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
$id=htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);

    include 'bd.php';
 
$res2=mysql_query("DELETE FROM `posts` WHERE `id`='$id'");
}
?>

Comment: и вообще посмотрите в инструментах разработчика ваш отправляемый запрос по сети каковы его данные и параметры

Comment: я это к чему $('#btndel').click(function() {
    $.post("system/del_post.php");
  }) перебьёт ваш id="btndel" onclick="delpost1()"

Comment: то есть, это лишнее? $('#btndel').click(function() { $.post("system/del_post.php"); })

Comment: да именно. Если нужно посмотрите и на $_POST['id'] на сервере чтоб пришло то что вы ждете

Comment: приходит не то что я жду, это понятно даже без просмотра) потмоу что удаляется не та запись

Comment: как я понял, отправляется несколько айди что ли, а нужен только конкретной записи

Comment: да точно у вас выборка такая

Answer (score 0):

Уберите для начала

```
$('#btndel').click(function() {
    $.post("system/del_post.php");
})
```

поскольку он перебивает такой вызов `id="btndel" onclick="delpost1()"`

попробуйте так

```
onclick="delpost1(this)"
```

а сам

```
function delpost1(element){
    Snackbar.show({text: 'Удалено!', actionText: 'Закрыть!', duration: 100000});
    var dlt = $(element.form).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "system/del_post.php",
      data: dlt,
    });
  }
```

Comment: это убрал, пытаюсь дальше понять, что не так

Comment: дальше посмотрите в консоли что у вас в var dlt = $('.delpost').serialize(); console.log(dlt)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: dlt is not defined

Comment: да не суть var dlt = $('.delpost').serialize(); возвращает все формы а нужна конкретнаа

Comment: вот и думаю, как тогда делать по другому. но перешерстил столько статей, а толку то

Comment: обновил поробуйте

Comment: не удаляется(((

Comment: исправил как говорится

Comment: правильно же что я использую у формы не айди а класс? class="delpost"

Comment: У вас jquery вернет несколько форм. когда вы попросите по классу

Comment: а так смотрите. у формы класс `class="delpost"`
в js у меня принималась форма по классу `var dlt = $('.delpost').serialize();`
а по вашему способу как передается айди новости ?

Comment: я передаю this это конкретный svg, а нужно сериализовать его парента

Comment: а передать по сути надо инпут. хм, сейчас подумаю

Comment: да по сути нужен id в посте

Comment: а можно ли использовать каким то образом .val()  ?

Comment: попробуйте я поменял parent на parentElement

Comment: не выходит почему то

Comment: Обновил element parent

Comment: я вот таким способом смог получить айди поста, но он зараза всегда айди последнего поста. `var dlt = document.getElementsByName("id_post")[1].value;`
попробую сейчас еще раз ваш способ

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, удалить `onclick="delpost1()"` (и остальную js), и добавить событие на кнопки:

```
$('.delete-note').on('click', function (evt) {
  let block = $(this).closest('.delpost');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "system/del_post.php",
    data: {id: block.find('[name=id]').val()},
    success: function () {
      Snackbar.show({text: 'Удалено!', actionText: 'Закрыть!', duration: 100000});
      // тут удаление блока новости
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш овтет! но, увы, не работает((

Comment: Добавьте в ответ вывод всех постов

Comment: не понял, а подробнее чуть чуть? в ответ куда?

Comment: В вопрос свой добавьте

Comment: `$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM posts  WHERE status_post=1 ORDER BY date_create_post DESC limit '.$start_pos.', '.$perpage);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { `